# Is there any way to await an IAsyncResult in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

How can I use **await** with HttpWebRequest in Windows Phone 8 ?

Is there a way to make the IAsyncResult stuff work with await?

```
private async Task<int> GetCurrentTemperature()
{
  GeoCoordinate location = GetLocation();

  string url = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=";
  url += location.Latitude.ToString();
  url += ",";
  url += location.Longitude.ToString();
  url += "&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=MYKEY";

  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  webRequest.Method = "POST";
  webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(OnGotWebRequest), webRequest);
}

private void OnGotWebRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
  var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
  {
    string responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321335.aspx) to create a `Task<Stream>` from the `BeginGetRequestStream`/`EndGetRequestStream` methods. Then you can get rid of your `OnGotWebRequest` completely, and do the same thing for the response.

Note that currently you're calling `EndGetResponse` when a `BeginGetRequestStream` call completes, which is inappropriate to start with - you've got to call the `EndFoo` method to match the `BeginFoo` you originally called. Did you mean to call `BeginGetResponse`?

Comment: could you give us an example on how to create and use the Task<Stream>?

Comment: I've found a perfect working example in [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14098942/831825).

Answer (score 4):

If you install the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package, you get a few `async`-ready extension methods, including ones for `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I've stumbled these days upon [this blog post](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/async-targeting-pack-for-visual-studio-2012-why-its-useful-also-for-windows-phone-8-projects/), which explains how to use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package in WP8.