# Using Async methods inside IAsyncResult

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am implementing [TokenProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.tokenprovider.aspx) class from `Microsoft.ServiceBus` namespace.
I am overriding the following method

```
protected override IAsyncResult OnBeginGetToken(string appliesTo, string action, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback,
            object state)
{
    var token = GetCustomTokenAsync(appliesTo); //How to await?
     return new CompletedAsyncResult<SharedAccessSignatureToken>(token, callback, state);
}
```

But as mentioned in the comment above. GetCustomTokenAsync is an async method and how do I await without disturbing the signature of TokenProvider class? I wanted to make use of async nature of GetCustomTokenAsync and hence I am reluctant to use `.Result`. Is there any better way of solving this?

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733749/is-there-any-way-to-await-an-iasyncresult-in-windows-phone-8

Comment: http://tpodolak.com/blog/2016/02/12/using-asyncawait-iasyncresult-pattern/ may help

Answer (score 2):

You need to [create APM wrappers around a TAP method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#TapToApm).

This is not entirely straightforward, especially because the `End*` methods of `TokenProvider` do *not* follow the APM pattern.

Requirements and recommendations:

- `Task` implements `IAsyncResult`, so you can return a task.
- The `state` member has to be returned from the `IAsyncResult.AsyncState` property on that task, so the task you return *cannot* be one generated by `async` - you have to create it yourself via `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.
- The `callback` needs to be invoked when the operation completes.
- If you override `Begin*`, you *must* also override the matching `End*`.

The resulting code ends up being a bit complex. You can avoid the boilerplate by using the `ApmAsyncFactory.ToBegin` in my [AsyncEx.Tasks](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Tasks) library (currently, `ApmAsyncFactory` is only in the [prerelease build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/1.2.0-alpha-01)):

```
protected override IAsyncResult OnBeginGetToken(string appliesTo, string action,
    TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  return ApmAsyncFactory.ToBegin(GetCustomTokenAsync(appliesTo), callback, state);
}

protected override SecurityToken OnEndGetToken(IAsyncResult result,
    out DateTime cacheUntil)
{
  var ret = ApmAsyncFactory.ToEnd<SharedAccessSignatureToken>(result);
  cacheUntil = ...;
  return ret;
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to see how the sausage is made and do it all by hand, one option would be (keeping in mind where all the exceptions can go):

```
protected override IAsyncResult OnBeginGetToken(string appliesTo, string action,
    TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SharedAccessSignatureToken>(state,
      TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
  var _ = CompleteAsync(GetCustomTokenAsync(appliesTo), callback, tcs);
  // _ is ignored; it can never fault.
  return tcs.Task;
}

private static async Task CompleteAsync<TResult>(Task<TResult> task,
    AsyncCallback callback, TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs)
{
  try
  {
    tcs.TrySetResult(await task.ConfigureAwait(false));
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
  {
    tcs.TrySetCanceled(ex.CancellationToken);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    tcs.TrySetException(ex);
  }
  finally
  {
    // Invoke callback unsafely on the thread pool, so exceptions are global
    if (callback != null)
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => callback((IAsyncResult)state), tcs.Task);
  }
}

protected override SecurityToken OnEndGetToken(IAsyncResult result,
    out DateTime cacheUntil)
{
  var task = (Task<SharedAccessSignatureToken>)result;
  var ret = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  cacheUntil = ...;
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Task implement `IAsyncResult`? Why not use a `ContinueWith` to map to `CompletedAsyncResult` and return that task?

Comment: The task returned from `ContinueWith` will not have the correct `IAsyncResult.AsyncState`. Also, using `CompletedAsyncResult` at all makes the implementation synchronous rather than asynchronous.

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't use `IAsyncResult` at all, instead you should return a `Task<T>` and await that. Same thing goes for your `GetCustomTokenAsync` method.

Comment: That does not help with implementing a class that inherits from `TokenProvider`, which is the goal here.